# Evaluation metric for an ordering algorithm

Tags: natural-language-processing, string-metrics

There is a sentence with N words.

The words are randomly shuffled.

I have a heuristic algorithm that tries to restore the original order.

I want to evaluate my algorithm on a dataset of several hundred long sentences from the internet.

The main goal of the algorithm is that humans looking at the restored sentence will be able to easily know what the original sentence was. So I can evaluate my algorithm by asking humans to grade the quality of the restored order. However, this is very expensive.

Another option is to count the number of words that are in their correct position in each sentence, and divide by the total number of words in all sentences. However, this is not a good measurement of the quality, because, for example, if the only mistake of my algorithm is that it put the last word first, the resulting sentence will get a score of 0, although it is quite similar to the gold standard, and a human will easily notice this.

A third option is to find the minimum number of word moves that need to be done on the algorithm output in order to achieve the gold standard. However, this seems like a non-trivial task in itself.

Can you suggest a measurement that will be both meaningful and easy to implement?

Comment: Have a look at our questions about [tag:string-metrics]. There are many of them. Deciding which is "meaningful" depends on the domain and can not be decided for you, at least not without further detail. As far as I know, the only "good" way to evaluate metrics is to do studies asking people how "good" they feel sentences are and find a metric that correlates.

Comment: I am looking for a metric that is: A. simple to implement (so that I don't have to write another algorithm just to evaluate my algorithm...), B. widely used in the literature, especially in the NLP literature.

Comment: I suggest you the following: maximum number of correct $consecutive$ words divided by the total number of words in the sentence. You may have more than one subset of correct consecutive words, so taking the maximum gives you a metric which is not fooled by interleaved correct sequences which are not in their correct position. When the ratio is 1 the sentence is totally correct.You need at least 2 correct consecutive words: for a sentence consisting of $n$ words the minimum value attained for this metric is 0 when there is no such pair of words, 2/$n$ is the first value > 0 etc.

Comment: You may also consider a single word as correct independently of its position (a degenerate case). With this assumption, you also get the value 1/$n$ for the metric (even for a permutation of the words in which none of the words occupy the correct position). This way, you end up with a metric ranging from 0 to 1 in discrete steps of 1/$n$ where $n$ is the total number of words in the sentence.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi So you went from "meaningful" to "widely used" -- beware!

Comment: @Massimo Cafaro this is interesting, however, if the algorithm makes a single mistake of flipping two adjacent words, the score will be very different depending on whether these words are in the beginning/end or in the middle...

Comment: At the beginning or at the end the score is ($n$-2)/$n$; assuming $n$ is even, an error exactly in the middle corresponds to a score of (($n$-2)/2)/$n$. Yes, this is NOT strictly related to the number of flips required to obtain the correct sequence. But, in your question you are not tying (at least not explicitly) the value of the metric to the actual number of flips required to recover the sentence. If you want such a metric, the obvious one is ($n$ - #flips required)/$n$, but then the difficulty lies in the estimation of the number of flips required to recover the sentence.

Comment: Therefore, once you decide to avoid using the number of flips required, *no metric can be probably optimal*. You need to make a choice, and the metric proposed makes the choice of maximizing the correctness of a *single* subsequence of the sentence. When the subsequence becomes the actual sentence you have attained your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One standard measure is the [Kendall tau distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance), which is the number of "inversions", i.e. positions $i < j$ such that $\pi(i) > \pi(j)$. It is also the number of transpositions $(k \; k+1)$ you need to apply to sort $\pi$, or vice versa, the number of such transpositions needed to generate $\pi$. (So it's the distance metric in the Cayley graph of $S_n$ with respect to the transpositions $(k \; k+1)$, which form a generating set.)

Comment: I gave yesterday in the comments a metric based on this: ($n$ - #flips required)/$n$. However, it seems that the OP wants to stay away from determining the exact number of inversions. May be he wants a lower complexity algorithm, even though not exact.